# .Distinct() call not filtering

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, selectlistitem

I'm attempting to use `AsEnumerable` to pull an Entity Framework `DbContext` query into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. This will be used as a model property that populates a drop down in the view.

However, each query keeps returning duplicate entries, despite having `Distinct()` called.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateCodeList { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DivCodeList { get; set; }    

DivCodeList =
    db.MarketingLookup.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Division).Distinct().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = x.Division,
                        Value = x.Division
                    }).ToList();

StateCodeList =
    db.MarketingLookup.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.State).Distinct().Select(x => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = x.State,
                        Value = x.State
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for `Distinct` to have effect, your sequence must contains objects of a type that implements the `IEquatable` interface, *if the type is a custom type*.

As it is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Distinct returns distinct elements from a sequence **by using the
>   default equality comparer** to compare values.

One workaround, in order to avoid the above, since I can conclude that you don't need the whole object rather one property of it, would be to project each element of your sequence to the `Division` and then make the `OrderBy` and calling the `Distinct`:

```
var divisions = db.MarketingLookup.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(ml=>ml.Division)
                                  .OrderBy(division=>division) 
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .Select(division => new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                     Text = division,
                                     Value = division
                                  }).ToList();
```

For further documentation on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation!! One quick edit - the `Text` and `Value` simply needed to be applied to `x`, not `x.Division` since `x` was assigned the value I'm looking for.

Comment: @NealR I just saw the edit of your comment and I corrected it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option (and one which our company/team uses frequently) is to add in a static extension method (we have an extensions library).

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(e => seenKeys.Add(keySelector(e)));
}
```

Which can then be called like this;

```
var divisions = db.MarketingLookup.AsEnumerable().DistinctBy(d => d.PrimaryKey)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Division, Value = x.Division }).ToList();
```

You can use whichever property of `MarketingLookup` you like, in the `DistinctBy()` call in order to pull out the desired records.